# how to define if statement when the range is inside the range

Tags: excel

i want to ask about excel if function. when i have a range of the data that i want to select with if function is like this

1. A1 get check Value from C1 range 5-10 tons Then show to A1 as "Colt"
2. A1 get check Value from C1 range 11-22 tons Then show to A1 as "Fuso"
3. A1 get check Value from C1 range 15-22 tons Then show to A1 as "Kontainer20"
4. A1 get check Value from C1 range 25-40 tons Then show to A1 as "Kontainer40"
5. A1 get check Value from C1 range 23-50 tons Then show to A1 as "Gandeng"
6. A1 get check Value from C1 range 50-55 tons Then show to A1 as "Trailer"

I have try to make it use this `fx function` in excel but not work. i use this
`=IF(5000<J4<10000;"Truck Colt Diesel";IF(11000<J4<22000;"Truck Fuso/Engkel";IF(15000<J4<22000;"Truck Container20'";IF(25000<J4<40000;"Truck Container40'";IF(23000<J4<50000;"Truck Gandeng/Tronton'";IF(50000<J4<55000;"Truck Bak Trailler";"-"))))))`

The data:

[image]

Comment: You have an `11-22` range and also a `15-22` range, what if it's `16` tons, is it "Fuso" or "Kontainer20"?  You do it again with `25-40` and `23-50`.  This uncertainty will likely cause inaccurate results.  In addition there are gaps in your ranges.  What happens if it's 52?

Comment: i got that range from my friend. he need my help.
im confuse.. i was asking to them. when it has range outside the range that he give to me its ok for me.
but when i see the range that's not possible to do. i think

Comment: i have same thinking from what you say `this uncertainty will likely cause inaccurate results`

Comment: I *think* you could use a Vlookup for this...Can you show your data, and the expected output?

Comment: @BruceWayne i've sent the data by picture. i dont know how to sent it

Comment: @BruceWayne in column `Input` when i input a number  inside the range at A1 then it will give output at `E1 as Type in the range ` and `F1 as Type Netto in the range`

Comment: @BruceWayne I think using `VLOOKUP` still can solve this i have try it

Comment: Is your input a number, i.e. `22000` and you want to then return `Fuso`?  Also, Gandeng and Kontainer 20' have the same Netto...is that correct? How do you know when to choose which?

Comment: Input number like `20000` then returning like `Fuso,Gandeng,or Kontainer`

Comment: i forgot netto has different function

Comment: Why does `20000` return those three? Can you please add some sample inputs and expected output to your question?

Comment: not those three.. i mean one of them.